# $\oint_C \frac{\sin(z)}{e^z z^3}dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

Evaluate the given integral
$$
\oint_{C}\frac{\sin\left(\,{z}\,\right)}{{\rm e}^{z}z^{3}}
\,{\rm d}z,$$
where $C$ is the circle
$\left\vert\,{z - 1}\,\right\vert = 3$.

I'm stuck, I don't know which integration method to use, any hint, please $?$ :(

Comment: see here [Cauchy's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem), the integrand is holomorphic on the region $|z-1| \le 3$, the assertion cliamed in the theorem holds.

Comment: @xzm The integrand is not holomorphic at $z=0$.

Comment: Ohh, yes yes, then apply [theorem of residue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem)

Comment: @gary, it’s not holomorphic? I’ve probably stared at it too long, it looks analytic to me with a pole of order two at the origin. Thanks!

Comment: @Aruralreader I claimed that it is not holomorphic at $z=0$. You say it has a pole of order $2$ at $z=0$. What is the issue here? If it has a pole of order $2$ at the origin, it cannot be holomorphic there.

Comment: @gary, I doubt there’s any issue here but mine. And thank you too, I simply need to dig out a book to refresh my memory, it’s been too many years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Cauchy's formula: $$f''(z_0)= \frac{2!}{2\pi i}\oint_{\partial D} \frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^3}d z,$$ where $f(z)$ requires to be holomorphic inside domain $D$.

In your case take $f(z) = \frac{\sin z}{e^z}$ and $z_0=0$. $$f'(z) = \frac{\cos z - \sin z }{e^{z}}$$ and $$f''(z) = \frac{-\sin z - \cos z - \cos z + \sin z}{e^z} = \frac{-2\cos z}{e^z}.$$ So the integral is $\frac{2\pi i}{2} f''(0) = -2\pi i $